# Combining mysql tables

Tags: mysql, union

How do I combine table `X and Y`:

```
table X (columnA, columnB, columnC)
table Y (columnA, columnB, columnD)
```

to get (columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD) ?

I am expecting to see NULL values...

To be more specific, here are the contents of the tables:

```
tableX:
A   B   C
1 | 0 | 0
2 | 0 | 0

tableY:
A   B   D
3 | 0 | 0
4 | 0 | 0

result:
A   B   C   D
1 | 0 | 0 | NULL
2 | 0 | 0 | NULL
3 | 0 | NULL | 0
4 | 0 | NULL | 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think he is expecting to join, just concatenate:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC, null as columnD
FROM tableX
UNION ALL
SELECT columnA, columnB, null as columnC, columnD
FROM tableY
```

Comment: This is good, except columnD would be named as "null" in table: tableZ(columnA, columnB, columnC, NULL)

Answer (score 0):

if `columnA` of both table(x&y) are referenced then use below

```
SELECT x.columnA,x.columnB,x.columnC,y.columnD
FROM tableX x
LEFT JOIN tabley y ON y.columnA=x.columnA
```